# Yii CGridView filter not working on one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, yii, cgridview

Okay. Here we go.
I'm having a regular CGridView that filters my data.

Here's the header:
[image: The header of the CGridView]

All filters except “On board” work just fine. And the thing is: it doesn't work on “serialize” javascript stage.
So when jquery.yiigridview.js runs this code:

```
$('body').undelegate(inputSelector, 'change').delegate(inputSelector, 'change', function(){
                var data = $(inputSelector).serialize();
                if(settings.pageVar!==undefined)
                    data += '&'+settings.pageVar+'=1';
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update(id, {data: data});
            });
```

Serialize returns “Anketa[onboard]=0” whatever I write into the text field.
I tried all types of controls (when I thought it was server-side problem):

```
array(
    'name' => 'onboard',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value'=>'$data->getOnBoardLabel()',
    //'filter' => CHtml::activeCheckBox($model,'onboard'),
    //'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'onboard',Lookup::items('onboard')),
    'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model,'onboard'),
),
```

and nothing changed. It still doesn't want to send proper value of the filter.

What should I do guys?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What type of field is `$model->onboard`? is it a number, text, or a foreign key?

Comment: Just a number. It's 0, 1 or 2

Comment: So You want to place a dropdownlist as a filter?

Comment: I want this filter to work. Now it doesn't with any type of control (dropdown, radio or text).

Comment: Added an answr. Pls check its working or not

Answer (score 0):

Since the `$model->onboard` is an enum as you specified in comments, you may want to use a dropdownlist filter. To render a render a filter in `CDataColumn` you have to specify it as an array. So the code will be

```
array(
    'name' => 'onboard',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value'=>'$data->getOnBoardLabel()',
    'filter' => Lookup::items('onboard'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys.
There were another noboard control on the page. So serialize behaved wierdly.